# ZIO, Provide environment from Effect

Tags: scala, zio

Starting with *ZIO* I am trying to convert an exiting application to a pure functional one. This application depends on an Http and an Frp client. They are both configured from a configuration file and optional command line arguments.

The current flow parse the arguments then read the configuration file and merge both. The resulting `Configuration` is passed to some components that need the Http and Ftp client.

Now, if I want to convert that to ZIO, I can naively create such flow :

```
val flow = for {
  options <- ZIO.succeed("Options")
  configs <- ZIO.succeed(s"Config + $options")
  result  <- ZIO.succeed("...") // This require the "configs"
} yield ()
```

Unfortunately, I cannot provide the `configs` since it is produced into the for comprehension itself.

My question is: How can we provide the result of one effect as environment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `.provide(configs)`, why not?

More generally you can do `io1.flatMap(io2.provide)` to run effect `io1` and then provide the result to another effect `io2`. There's even a shortcut for this: `io1 >>> io2`.